# Ad Scheduling Is Not Visible

Tags: google-ads-api

In my Google Analytic account when I go to Campaign Settings the "Ad Scheduling" tab is not shown. Any ideas why?

I have followed this article:

```
http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2014/07/30/ad-scheduling
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it..

Custom ad scheduling is available for campaigns with “All features” enabled. If your campaign sub-type is set to “Standard”, you won’t see ad scheduling as an option in your campaign’s Settings tab. You may need to change your campaign sub-type to “All features”